# How do you "shift" a sum?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How do you "shift" a sum?

How to turn $$\int \:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^n\times \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}}$$

to

$$\int \:\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^{n-1}\times \frac{x^{2n-1}}{2^{2n-1}}$$

can someone please explain the logic behind this? When you shift the sum to the right by $1$, so you do $-1$, but I don't get why the $x^{2n+1}$ moved by $2$?

Thanks all <3 danke

Comment: As you noted, to undo an index shift of $+1$ we "do $-1$", but "doing $-1$" means making the substitution $n\to n-1$. Applying that substitution to $2n+1$ gives $$2(n-1)+1 =(2n-2)+1=2n-1$$ So, those exponents "moved by $2$" because the $n$ in them is multiplied by $2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from the first expression, we will note $\tilde{n} = n + 1$ so that $n = \tilde{n} - 1$. Now everywhere we see $n$ in the first expression we replace $n$ by $\tilde{n}-1$. This gives,

$$\int \:\sum _{\tilde{n}-1=0}^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^{\tilde{n}-1}\times \frac{x^{2(\tilde{n}-1)+1}}{2^{2(\tilde{n}-1)+1}} = \int \:\sum _{\tilde{n}=1}^{\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^{\tilde{n}-1}\times \frac{x^{2\tilde{n}-1}}{2^{2\tilde{n}-1}}$$

in which we can trivially rename $\tilde{n}=n$ to get the expression you want. The difference you were talking about comes from the multiplication by $2$. One thing you must be careful about: the upper bound $\infty$ was basically untouched but this is coincidental. When doing these manipulations we should write the first expression as
$$\int \:\sum _{n=0}^{n=\infty }\:\left(-1\right)^n\times \frac{x^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}}$$

and then replace everywhere $n$ by $\tilde{n}-1$. This worked out in this problem because $\tilde{n}-1=\infty\implies \tilde{n}=\infty$ and so the bound was unchanged.

Answer (score 1):

Expand the sigma notation, this will be quite obvious:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_{2n+1} &= a_1 + a_3 + a_5 + \dots \\&= a_{2\cdot \color{red}1-1} + a_{2\cdot \color{red}2-1}+a_{2\cdot \color{red}3-1}+\dots \\&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2\color{red}n-1}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

This "shift" is actually called "reindexing." In general, if you add $y$ to the starting index, then you should subtract $y$ from every $n$ in your summand. i.e.

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f(n) = \sum_{n=y}^\infty f(n-y)$$